# Оператор typeof обработка массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
function isNumber(val) {
    return typeof val === 'number';
}
let allNumbers = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
console.log(isNumber(allNumbers))
```

При обработке массива выдает `false`. Если написать содержимое массива в виде аргументов, то `true`.
 Как обработать числовой массив, чтобы метод вернул `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для обработки массива Вам потребуется немного иной подход)

Функция не срабатывает для каждого аргумента переданного массива отдельно. Она отрабатывает, как ей и полагается, для одного переданного значения

---

В Вашем случае, когда Вы отдаете ей массив, то получаете следующую картину:

```js
function isNumber(val) {
    console.log(typeof val); // object
    return typeof val === 'number';
}
let allNumbers = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(isNumber(allNumbers)); // false
```

---

Чтобы проверить, все ли элементы массива удовлетворяют заданному условию, Вам следует использовать метод [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), который как раз таки

> проверяет, удовлетворяют ли все элементы массива условию, заданному в передаваемой функции.

Приведу простенький пример:

```js
function isNumber(val) {
    return typeof val === 'number';
}
// Обозначим функцию для обработки массива
function areNumbers(arr) {
    // Передадим в every() лямбду, которая принимает элемент массива и возвращает bool
    return arr.every(x => isNumber(x));
    // Или короче:
    // return arr.every(isNumber);
}
let allNumbers = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(areNumbers(allNumbers)); // true
```

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам разобраться в Вашей проблеме!
Удачи в Ваших начинаниях!

Comment: `.every(x => isNumber(x))` => `.every(isNumber)`

Comment: @Grundy понятно дело) Я для наглядности, ибо, судя по вопросу, ТС пока не знает про лямбды и то, что функции можно передавать в качестве аргумента) Ладно, чтобы не навлекать Вашего праведного гнева, добавлю)

Answer (score 1):

Ты передаешь в функцию массив чисел, а у массивов в JS тип "object". Используй метод массива "forEach" для обработки каждого элемента отдельно